# Kubernetes PV/PVC with Ceph or an alternative?

Tags: storage, kubernetes

Since I don't have direct access to the storage, but want to run `Kubernetes` in my own environment: Which software (on a VM) do I use to provide `PV/PVC` via the `file system`? I have heard about `Ceph`. What do I have to consider? Are there alternatives?

If this is too general: Can I get around `Ceph` (not that I wanted to) when I can only use the file system in a VM (yes/no)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide some more information regarding your environment.

Many depends on your needs. You mentioned `CephFS`, as it is supported in Kubernetes. **However** as you want to use VM it might be really hard. In [this blog](http://jmjoo.blogspot.com/2018/08/ceph-storage.html) you can find information:

> It should not be run off of VMs themselves since it is not optimized for a VM Kernel. This advice is coming directly from Red Hat. Unfortunately this means that smaller use cases are out of the question since it literally requires 10 physical machines, each with their own OS to become individual OSD nodes.

You should read about Kubernetes [Types of Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes). Another important thing is [Access Mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) of each `PV`. To apply `PersistentVolume` on VM you can use:

**emptyDir** - An emptyDir volume is first created when a Pod is assigned to a Node, and exists as long as that Pod is running on that node. In addition, if `Container` crashing does NOT remove a Pod from a node, so the data in an emptyDir volume is safe across Container crashes.

Example and more information can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir).

**HostPath** - will work only in a one node cluster. It will not work in multi-node cluster.

> A hostPath volume mounts a file or directory from the host node’s filesystem into your Pod. This is not something that most Pods will need, but it offers a powerful escape hatch for some applications.

More details with example can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath).

**GlusterFS** - In the future, if you would consider more versatile solution you could check `GlusterFS`. It's well described in [this article](https://medium.com/@naikaa/persistent-storage-kubernetes-67f0f1e1f31e).

**Local** - Introduced in Kubernetes 1.14. A local volume represents a mounted local storage device such as a disk, partition or directory. 
Details with example can be found on [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local).

Comment: Look out. I have selected and deployed GlusterFS + Heketi. Unfortunately, it was only then that I discovered that GlusterFS is not suitable for Redis and databases such as Postgres. I regularly receive the following error messages in access mode RWO: Kubernetes event `Warning FailedMount transport endpoint is not connected`, Postgres log `invalid record length at 0/7EDC2F0: wanted 24, got 0` and `WARNING:  corrupted statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"`.

Comment: You can add OpenEBS and Longhorn to your list?!